# Slow MySQL query

Tags: mysql, performance, filesort

Hey I have a very slow MySQL query. I'm sure all I need to do is add the correct index but all the things I try don't work.

The query is:

```
SELECT DATE(DateTime) as 'SpeedDate', avg(LoadTime) as 'LoadTime'
FROM SpeedMonitor
GROUP BY Date(DateTime);
```

The Explain for the query is:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  SpeedMonitor    ALL                 7259978 Using temporary; Using filesort
```

And the table structure is:

```
CREATE TABLE `SpeedMonitor` (
  `SMID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `DateTime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `LoadTime` double unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`SMID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7258294 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Wait, it's slow as in it takes a long time to complete?

Comment: yeh, because it is copying to a temporary table

Comment: I've answered to you, but I'm asking how many records there are in that table

Comment: it says in the explain message that there are 7259978

Comment: I don't think your table design makes much sense.  Because of it you are asking the query to group by a datetime field which includes milliseconds so it can caculate the average of the time field?  How many records will have the exact same date timestamp?  My guess you are looking for the average loadtime per day in which case you would want to have the group by on the date only?  Am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're just asking for two columns in your query, so indexes could/should go there:

- DateTime
- LoadTime

Another way to speed your query up could be split DateTime field in two: date and time.
This way db can group directly on date field instead of calculating DATE(...).

**EDITED:**
If you prefer using a trigger, create a new column(DATE) and call it **newdate**, and try with this (I can't try it now to see if it's correct):

```
CREATE TRIGGER upd_check BEFORE INSERT ON SpeedMonitor
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SET NEW.newdate=DATE(NEW.DateTime);
END
```

**EDITED AGAIN:**
I've just created a db with the same table speedmonitor filled with about 900,000 records.
Then I run the query S`ELECT newdate,AVG(LoadTime) loadtime FROM speedmonitor GROUP BY newdate` and it took about 100s!!
Removing index on newdate field (and clearing cache using `RESET QUERY CACHE` and `FLUSH TABLES`), the same query took 0.6s!!!
Just for comparison: query `SELECT DATE(DateTime),AVG(LoadTime) loadtime FROM speedmonitor GROUP BY DATE(DateTime)` took 0.9s.
So I suppose that the index on newdate is not good: remove it.
I'm going to add as many records as I can now and test two queries again.

**FINAL EDIT:**
Removing indexes on newdate and DateTime columns, having **8mln records** on speedmonitor table, here are results:

- selecting and grouping on newdate column: **7.5s**
- selecting and grouping on DATE(DateTime) field: **13.7s**

I think it's a good speedup.
Time is taken executing query inside mysql command prompt.

Comment: 2 separate indexes or 1 joint index?

Comment: splitting the fields isnt really an option at the moment

Comment: @Jonny Shaw: is your db still in use? Is there an active app writing to it? The number of records is growing up?

Comment: yeh the number of records increases by about 300,000 every day.

Comment: @Jonny Shaw: your engine will blow executing that query in some time. Can't you really change tabledef and split DateTime field? How many times do you need to execute that query?

Comment: @Jonny Shaw: just to understand how much can the query be improved with this update, try to create a new column and fill this with DATE(DateTime) for existing records. Execute the query using this new field and take a look at elapsed time

Comment: that query is part of our admin section so only gets run a couple of times a day. is it possibly that i could create a trigger to populate a date field when a record is inserted? as opposed to altering the script that is inserting

Comment: @Jonny Shaw: I edited my code inserting a trigger. Please, test it because I can't now, sorry

Comment: Got the following error.
Error: Updating of NEW row is not allowed in after trigger

Comment: should i also add an index for the new field?

Comment: @Jonny Shaw: does it work? How long takes query to execute? I'm curious :)

Comment: im just waiting for new records to get inserted. which is every 10 minutes.

Comment: @Jonny Shaw: I can't go to bed if I don't know ;)

Comment: it keeps loading it from the cache. which is good i suppose but that speed is 0.331 seconds

Comment: there was an error in your trigger so data was not being inserted.

SET NEW.newdate=DATE(DateTime); needed to be SET NEW.newdate=DATE(NEW.DateTime);

Comment: and running the query took 60 seconds

Comment: @Jonny Shaw: is it good or not? How long did it take before? I corrected my post, thanks.

Comment: still very slow. although now it doesnt use temporary table. it spends 60 seconds sending data, according to the profiler. not sure what that means

Comment: @Jonny Shaw: how long did it take before? How much longer than 60s?

Comment: @Jonny Shaw: I need to go to bed, it's 3 a.m. here and at 6 I have to wake up. Can we go on later? See you...

Comment: It still takes that long even with the index on the newdate column?

Comment: @Jonny Shaw: here I am. Try using EXPLAIN EXTENDED and see if you/we can have more infos... it's really TOO strange that using newdate column (indexed and without the need to have DATE(...) on GROUP) uery time remains the same...

Comment: @Jonny Shaw: I'll try to create a db like yours to try locally and see what can I do...

Comment: Marco: removing this index has defiantly sped up this query. It is not running in about 10 seconds. Great Work!

Comment: @Jonny Shaw: problem solved, that's why SO exists!! :) Thanks to @Joel C, when someone likes your work, that makes you feel good :)

Comment: @Jonny Shaw, @Joel C: if you're interested, I'm asking the reason of this strange behaviour [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5686343/why-an-index-can-make-a-query-really-slow)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're using a function in your `GROUP BY` clause, so MySQL has to evaluate the expression `Date(DateTime)` on every record before it can group the results. I'd suggest adding a calculated field for `Date(DateTime)`, which you could then index and see if that helps your performance.

Comment: what do you mean by a calculated field?

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right, I've already suggested this... but if this db is in use (I mean is not finished), he should change the logic inside the app writing to db. I don't know if he can...

Comment: @Jonny Shaw: I think he means taht you should add a new column in which you have to store only the DATE part of DateTime field

Comment: the database is currently in a live environment and filling up very quickly. so that wouldn't be something that could be changed easily.

Comment: Ah, turns out MySQL doesn't support either calculated fields or indexes on views, so it sounds like your only options are to add the Date field and populate it yourself in code or using a trigger, or switch to a different database platform.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you'll permit me to point out that before you put a table into production with millions of records you should seriously consider how that data is going to be used and plan accordingly.

What is happening right now is that your query cannot use any indexes and hence scans the entire table building a response. Not the fastest way to work with relatively large tables.

You have some things to consider if you want to get to a better state:

1. How fast is it collecting data?
2. How much history do you need?
3. How granular are your reporting requirements?
4. Are you able to suspend logging to make table changes?

If the answer is "No" to the last question you could always create a new table/solution and start writing records there... importing in old data if/as needed.

Reporting granularity is important as you could, for example, compress a day's worth of data into 24 records. Load the current day into an index free loading table and then process it the next day into per hour averages. Name each loading table based on the sample date and you can delete old tables as processed.

Of course, hourly may not be fine grained enough.

Depending on your retention needs you might want to consider some type of partitioned storage. This can let you query against subsets of sample data and simply drop or archive old partitions when they are no long current enough to be relevant.

Anyhow, you seem to be on the edge of having some type of massive sampling, reporting and/or monitoring system (particularly if you were reporting on a variety of sites or pages with different characteristics). You may want to put some effort into designing this so it will fit your needs... ;)