# Why an index can make a query really slow?

Tags: mysql

Some day I answered a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5642880/slow-mysql-query/5642908#5642908) on SO (accepted as correct), but the answer left me with a great doubt.
Shortly, user had a table with this fields:

```
id INT PRIMARY KEY
dt DATETIME (with an INDEX)
lt DOUBLE
```

The query `SELECT DATE(dt),AVG(lt) FROM table GROUP BY DATE(dt)` was really slow.
We told him that (part of) the problem was using **DATE(dt)** as field and grouping, but db was on a production server and wasn't possible to split that field.
So (with a trigger) was inserted another field `da DATE (with an INDEX)` filled automatically with **DATE(dt)**. Query `SELECT da,AVG(lt) FROM table GROUP BY da` was a bit faster, but with about 8mln records it took about 60s!!!
I tried on my pc and finally I discovered that, removing the index on field **da** query took only 7s, while using *DATE(dt)* after removing index it took 13s.
I've always thought an index on column used for grouping could really speed the query up, not the contrary (8 times slower!!!).
Why? Which is the reason?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: @FractalizeR: on my pc I have MySQL5.5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you still need to read all the data from both index + data file. Since you're not using any `where` condition - you always will have the query plan, that access all the data, row by row and you can do nothing with this.

If performance is important for this query and it is performed often - I'd suggest to cache the results into some temporary table and update it hourly (daily, etc).

Why it becomes slower: because in index data is already sorted and when mysql calculates cost of the query execution it thinks that it will be better to use already sorted data, then group it, then calculate agregates. But it is not in this case.

Comment: I don't think this explains why he got performance boost on queries AFTER an index was removed.

Comment: @zerkms: but MySql has to `group by` indexed column, so I think it should be faster aggregating _close_ records. It's clear that what I think is not what happens in reality :) but I'd like to understand it well, because I work with MySql and in future I could make the same mistake of our user (maybe without understanding the reason until I have a lot of records)

Comment: @FractalizeR: when he has an index - mysql need to go index to get the rowid (physical attribute, the offset in data file) - after that go to data file, read that row, then back to index, etc. Instead of this you can just read the data file **sequentially**. Sequential read is faster, than a lot of repetitive random reads. It is not a bug, it is expected behaviour, caused by not very accurate query cost evaluation calculated by optimizer.

Comment: @Marco: even though it has "close" values near (since they are sorted) - mysql still needs to go to data file to calculate aggregated values. Remove `AVG(field)` and try to query: `SELECT da FROM table GROUP BY da`. It should be fast.

Comment: @FractalizeR: ps: yes, it looks like that bug, sorry. But it is fixed according to comments there :-S Well, I think this behaviour has the same roots: wrong CBO calculations.

Comment: @zerkms: I can't try until monday, sorry. But I'll do that... I'm really curious!

Comment: @zerkms BTW, EXPLAIN either with index or without it gives the same plan `1  SIMPLE  ttt  system  NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL  0  0.00  const row not found`

Comment: @FractalizeR: execution plan can depend on a lots of things. Table fragmentation, for example. I think OP needs to perform `ANALYZE` and `OPTIMIZE` and re-do the tests (and share explains)

Comment: @zerkms Agreed. Actually, I'm very interested in this.

Comment: @FractalizeR: yep, i'd also like to see the results without aggregate over `lt` and after optimizing. Hope OP will bump this topic in monday.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because of this or similiar MySQL bug: [Index degrades sort performance and optimizer does not honor IGNORE INDEX](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=21174)

Comment: Wow, I didn't even know about it, thanks. Anyway they're talking about MySQL 5.1 and they told a patch was already committed...

Answer (score 0):

I remember the question as I was going to answer it but got distracted with something else. The problem was that his table design wasnt taking advantage of a clustered primary key index.

I would have re-designed the table creating a composite clustered primary key with the date as the leading part of the index. The sm_id field is still just a sequential unsigned int to guarantee uniqueness.

```
drop table if exists speed_monitor;
create table speed_monitor 
(
created_date date not null,
sm_id int unsigned not null,
load_time_secs double(10,4) not null default 0,
primary key (created_date, sm_id)
)
engine=innodb;

+------+----------+
| year | count(*) |
+------+----------+
| 2009 | 22723200 | 22 million
| 2010 | 31536000 | 31 million
| 2011 |  5740800 |  5 million
+------+----------+

select 
 created_date, 
 count(*) as counter,
 avg(load_time_secs) as avg_load_time_secs
from
 speed_monitor
where
 created_date between '2010-01-01' and '2010-12-31'
group by
 created_date
order by
 created_date
limit 7;

-- cold runtime

+--------------+---------+--------------------+
| created_date | counter | avg_load_time_secs |
+--------------+---------+--------------------+
| 2010-01-01   |   86400 |         1.66546802 |
| 2010-01-02   |   86400 |         1.66662466 |
| 2010-01-03   |   86400 |         1.66081309 |
| 2010-01-04   |   86400 |         1.66582251 |
| 2010-01-05   |   86400 |         1.66522316 |
| 2010-01-06   |   86400 |         1.66859480 |
| 2010-01-07   |   86400 |         1.67320440 |
+--------------+---------+--------------------+
7 rows in set (0.23 sec)
```

Comment: yes, but its date field was not a date, but a datetime, infact he had to use DATE(...). Anyway, after inserting field _da_ you would have declared PK as composite (id,da)? Well, probably you're right, but believe me: if db was mine I shouldn't have thought about this.. I would have the same problem as the other user without knowing the reason ;)

Comment: ok so go with the add a new date field but make that new field part of the clustered composite key